# JVM performance with these garbage collection settings

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have an enterprise level Java application that serves a few thousand users per day.  This is a JAXB web service on weblogic 10.3.6 (Java 1.6 JVM), using Hibernate to hit an Oracle database.  It also calls other web services.

We have it tuned the following GC settings on our production system:

```
-server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

What is the effect of this GC sizing?  The hardware has more than enough capacity to handle it.

I know that this sets the heap size and perm gen at a stable level.  But what's the impact of that when you eventually have to do garbage collection?

To me it seems that it would make GC happen less frequently, but take longer when it does happen.  Does that sound correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it would make GC happen less frequently, but take longer when it does happen

It might, it depends on your use case.  You might even find that the GC is shorter in rare case.

A 2 GB heap isn't that much and I would use up to 26 GB without worrying about heap size.  Above this size memory accesses are a little slower or use more memory.

Comment: Thanks, that is kind of what I figured would happen.  So the group that is doing this is doing it right - they are setting the heap sizes properly and leaving them that way.  They've upped the heaps to 2 GB.

Comment: @AlanDelimon You want to set the maximum heap size to the point where you would rather the process fail than use more memory. You don't have to set the minimum to be the maximum.  I would set the minimum to the amount you expect the JVM to use, which could be less than the max.

Answer (score 2):

I would say please monitor the GC before deciding on the sizing as you never know how the application will behave under load. Have a look at this [link](http://www.techpaste.com/2011/12/30/steps-java-virtual-machine-tuning-sun-hotspot-jrockit-garbage-collection/) and [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078645/java-se/jvm-performance-optimization-part-3-garbage-collection.html) it has some good references about GC and tools to calculate the same.

Answer (score 1):

Setting -Xmx & -Xms and PermSize & MaxPermSize to equal sizes will stop the JVM from resizing the heaps based on your requirement. These resizes are expensive as they trigger a Full GC.

-server will allow the JVM to make use of Server Compiler which will do more aggressive optimizations before compiling your code to native assembly instructions. Although now-a-days any machine with 2 or more cores and 2GB+ of memory will have server compiler on by default.

Increasing the memory doesn't always fix a problem. Sometimes adding more memory will be an overhead.

If you need details regarding GC, you can try this [link](http://learnerslog.com/2014/07/garbage-collection-in-java/)

The very reason to tune something is to improve your application's performance and there by achieve your throughput and latency goals.